# what is the difference between g++ in android and g++ in ubuntu?

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, g++

I try to the same simple code, that which one is in the Android(4.2.2) and another one is in the Ubuntu(15.04), but with a similar code I get error in the Ubuntu. Also in the Android works very well, but in the Ubuntu even does not compiling.

> initialize without / = / syntax and uses / ( ) / syntax

code :

```
int i(1); /// ok
char c('a'); /// ok
float f(4.444); /// ok
double d(4.34343433434); /// ok
char* cs("stack over flow"); /// ok
char I[]("stack over flow"); /// can not initialize by g++ in Ubuntu
```

in Android (c4droid):

[image]

in Ubuntu (code block):

[image]

both of them use the g++ compiler

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like they're different versions of the `g++` compiler.

Comment: maybe, I have no idea :(

Comment: You showed the output of `g++ --version` on Ubuntu, what does it show on Android?

Comment: I think in the c4droid g++ is upper than in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

In standard c++ built-in arrays cannot be constructed with constructor-like call. You should use `{}` brackets instead. It's very similar to templates. Non-type template arguments can't be deduced from constructors (just like any template arguments)

Comment: Can you find a relevant standard quote?

Comment: Well, but is not g++ compiler standard in the Android ?

Comment: @k-five: standard OS compiler doesn't mean standard c++. Many compilers implement some extensions that apply only to them.
@Anton Savin: I can't find any quote that prohibits this construction, but as long as I remember arrays can be only initialized with initializer lists (except for character arrays) or not initialized at all. Construction `(...)` with variadic arguments would make it similar to calling a constructor with variadic arguments, which built-in arrays don't have.

Comment: In my linux box (arch linux, with g++ 5.3.0) it compiles without problem. Indeed, it only complies about this line: `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] char* cs("stack over flow"); /// ok`

Comment: It must not be this form, I test the code in cpp.sh and give me error, too :(

Comment: I test the code in the Android and this time in / cppdorid / and give 2 error :((((

Comment: @Amadeus It must be gcc extension. Clang fails to compile such code.

Comment: I test that and does not work in linux and works in / c4droid / ---- for warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] char* cs("stack over flow"); ---- if can "const" does not get ERROR

Comment: Here is clang error that I do expect: `error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal`

Comment: @BlackMoses Hi, using clang++ (arch linux clang version 3.7.1) i've got exactly the same message as using g++ (`warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings] char* cs("stack over flow"); /// ok`) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7f9247fe8b0458d

Comment: New compile the code with g++ 5.2.1 and result : Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ------------ I upgrade my Ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10 and now my g++ version is 5.2.1 and I again compile the code and execute successful :)